# Deleting numbers in a string using regex

Tags: python

Replacing numbers with a placeholder in a string inclding decimals and percentages using re in Python

```py
def remove_numbers(text):
    remove = re.sub(r"\W\d\S*", " [DD]", text,)
    return remove
```

The function works fine on this sample string. sample = "I can give you 10% of 100,000 to you. The thing went up by 10% so it costs 12.25 euros now.
But if a string starts with a number, the first numer does not get replaced by the placeholder.

Comment: where did i work perfectly, can you add that, also add more example of input and output

Comment: sample = I can give 50% of 100,000 to you in cash. it went up by 2.3% and its costly.

Comment: Add this to the question instead, and the expected output

Comment: it worked on that string perfectly, but if the number is at the start of the string it dosent seem to work

Comment: What the expected output for  `I can give 50% of 100,000 to you in cash. it went up by 2.3% and its costly` ?

Comment: I can give [DD] of [DD] to you in cash. it went up by by [DD] and its costly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\W requires a character to be there, so when you try it with a number at the beginning it'll look like just \d\S*.

Use '\b' instead of '\w' to [match word boundaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-26):

```
def remove_numbers(text):
    remove = re.sub(r"\b\d\S*", "[DD]", text,)
    return remove
```

Or, keeping more in the spirit of your original code:

```
def remove_numbers(text):
    remove = re.sub(r"(\s|^)\d\S*", r"\1[DD]", text,)
    return remove
```

And use \d+ instead of \d if you want to also match multiple digits in a row.

Answer (score 1):

So looping through the replace method seems to be the easiest way to do this.

```
def remove_numbers(text):
    nums = '123456787980'
    for i in nums:
        text = text.replace(i, '[DD]')

    return text
```

Answer (score 1):

`\W` will not match at the start of string. It appears you are using `\W` to make sure that the number you are replacing is not a part of a word. This makes sense.  But, `\W` doesn't match at start-of-string.  You can use `\A` for that. But, you probably don't want to add a space when you are replacing at start-of-string. This can be done in a single regex, but I think it results in easier-to-read code if you do it in two steps.

```
import re

def remove_numbers(text):
    # replace internal numbers that are not a part of a word (adds a space)
    remove = re.sub(r"\W\d\S*", " [DD]", text,)
    # replace number at start of string (if any) (does not add a space)
    remove = re.sub(r"\A\d\S*", "[DD]", remove,)
    return remove

a = "3 foxes jumped over 3 fences"
b = remove_numbers(a)

print("before <{}>".format(a))
print("after <{}>".format(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import re
def remove_numbers(text):
    remove = re.sub(r"\W?\d\S*", " [DD]", text,)
    return remove.strip()

print(remove_numbers())
```

The `?` means 0 or more of the previous pattern

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to :

```
    remove = re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " [DD] ", text)
```

All code :

```
import re
def remove_numbers(text):
    s = re.sub("^\d+\s|\s\d+\s|\s\d+$", " [DD] ", text)

    return s

t1 = "3 foxes jumped over 3 fences"
print (remove_numbers(t1))
```

Output :

```
[DD] foxes jumped over [DD] fences
```